# Error in java (sift package)

Tags: java, bluetooth

I am getting an error with h following code:

http://www.codemiles.com/java/connecting-to-pc-from-mobile-using-bluetooth-in-java-t711.html

the error is:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\admin\My Documents\NetBeansProjects\sift\src\sift\PCServerCOMM.java:72: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class MOBILEOR_GUI

location: class sift.PCServerCOMM

MOBILEOR_GUI frame;



C:\Documents and Settings\admin\My Documents\NetBeansProjects\sift\src\sift\PCServerCOMM.java:79: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class MOBILEOR_GUI

location: class sift.PCServerCOMM

public PCServerCOMM(MOBILEOR_GUI frame


C:\Documents and Settings\admin\My Documents\NetBeansProjects\sift\src\sift\PCServerCOMM.java:199: 
cannot find symbol

symbol: class FrameImage

 new FrameImage(aa, 1);

C:\Documents and Settings\admin\My Documents\NetBeansProjects\sift\src\sift\PCServerCOMM.java:201: 
cannot find symbol

symbol: class SIFT

SIFT sift = new SIFT(path, "scale2.jpg", "welcome");


C:\Documents and Settings\admin\My Documents\NetBeansProjects\sift\src\sift\PCServerCOMM.java:201:
 cannot find symbol

symbol: class SIFT

SIFT sift = new SIFT(path, "scale2.jpg", "welcome");


C:\Documents and Settings\admin\My Documents\NetBeansProjects\sift\src\sift\PCServerCOMM.java:208: 
cannot find symbol

symbol: variable MOBILEOR_GUI

 MOBILEOR_GUI.AppendTostatus(sift.getATree().getMatchingInfo());


C:\Documents and Settings\admin\My Documents\NetBeansProjects\sift\src\sift\PCServerCOMM.java:241:
 cannot find symbol

symbol  : variable MOBILEOR_GUI

location: class sift.PCServerCOMM
MOBILEOR_GUI.AppendTostatus(msg + "\n");
```

7 errors

please help me out.i am new to java and doing project in java.

Comment: It seems there are some missing class files that should be in the classpath, how are you compiling?

Comment: thank you for reply.I am using net beans 6.7.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the comments on the forum page you mentioned (http://www.codemiles.com/java/connecting-to-pc-from-mobile-using-bluetooth-in-java-t711.html). You'll see that a lot of people are asking the same question there.

It simply means that the guy posted only a portion of his project, and this code can't work on its own, because it's missing the rest of the classes (such as `SIFT` and `MOBILEOR_GUI`, whatever they are). He says:

> these lines of codes not related to the connection of bluetooth , it is related to my project function , for example , SIFT is an object recognition algorithm .

You'll have to edit the code, understand which parts are relevant to you (i.e. everything that has to do with bluetooth connectivity) and which parts are only relevant to that guy's SIFT project.

Comment: thnk you.but there is no main class as well,what do i do?

Comment: You'll have to write your own main method. What the original code is doing is not the same as what you want to do, so in any case you'll have to write your own parts.